# error traversing xml in Python

Tags: python, xml

My attempts to traverse an xml file retrieved from a url has always failed. Though, it worked if I typed the xml file directly in the code such as:

```
    smplexml = ''' somexml'''
```

but I have been unsuccessful to make a code like:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import urllib

    xmlstr = urllib.urlopen('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml').read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
    print tree.find('name').text
```

this work. Please what am I doing wrongly? Sometimes I get an error message like:

```
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: if `tree.find('name')` doesn't find anything, it will return `None`. Which doesn't have an attribute `text`. You should find first, and make sure you actually found something before you try to use it. (and you could also use `findall` to find multiple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib

xmlstr = urllib.urlopen('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml').read()
tree = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
for food in tree:
    print food.find('name').text
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem.

Comment: Yes the loop makes it work. But I tried the same code with this xml retrieval: 'http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/gateway/ipsSearch.jsp?querytext=%28systematic%20review%20OR%20systematic%20literature%20review%20AND%20text%20mining%20techniques%29&pys=2009&&hc=5'. I attempted to extract text of say the "title" tag it didnt work.